# How to reverse a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a string in SQL stored in `@result` variable of type `Varchar(MAX)` like this:

```
Attributes >> Items >> Category >> Package
```

How can i get the reverse of this without impacting the performance of stored procedure .I want to break the string on the basis of `>>`.

```
Package >> Category >> Items >> Attributes
```

Comment: Are there at most four elements in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have at most four items in the string and none contain periods, then you can use `PARSENAME()`.

```
select (parsename(replace(@result, ' >> ', '.'), 1) + ' >> ' +
        parsename(replace(@result, ' >> ', '.'), 2) + ' >> ' +
        parsename(replace(@result, ' >> ', '.'), 3) + ' >> ' +
        parsename(replace(@result, ' >> ', '.'), 4)
       )
```

Another option is to split the string and reconstruct it.

Comment: Anytime you add any kind of code to a procedure it will impact the performance. This solution is extremely fast so the impact should be minimal and not likely to even be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Break the string into different parts using the delimiter `>>` the assign row_number to each row.

Then `Convert the rows into single string` delimited by `>>` order by desc.

This should work if you have more than 4 elements

```
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(5000)='',
        @String VARCHAR(5000)='Attributes >> Items >> Category >> Package'

SELECT @output += splt_data + ' >> '
FROM  (SELECT Row_number()
                OVER(
                  ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))                       rn,
              Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.bb.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) splt_data
       FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@String, '>>', '</M><M>')
                            + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
              CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(bb)) ou
ORDER  BY rn DESC
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
SELECT LEFT(@output, Len(@output) - 3) --Package >> Category >> Items >> Attributes
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're running SQL Server 2008, or newer, try:

```
    Select Reverse(@result)
```

Comment: Package << Category << Items << Attributes. Is that the output?

Comment: egakcaP >> yrogetaC >> smetI >> setubirttA

Comment: He said the string was stored in his variable. If he wants that string reversed, the simplest way to do that is to use the system function REVERSE(string_expression)

Comment: This isn't even close to what the OP stated they want.

Comment: The question is to reverse the words in the string, not the letters in the string.